# HTML5 Sound Stopping & Iphone

Tags: html, audio, google-chrome, ipod-touch

**intro:** I'm making a html5 game atm, and right now when the user taps the screen i have it playing a sound.

**ProblemA:** In chrome, the sound plays , but eventually stops playing all together even if i try to refresh the page ( the debug console doesnt show any errors either ) and i have to restart my browser to get the sound to play it again.

**ProblemB:** Also, the sound doesnt load on my ipod touch. But the game does when i dont load sounds.

i'm not using any api's or librarys. Any links to articles, or such would be helpful.

**Edit: Heres some sample code of what im doing.**

```
function loadSound(name,url){ 
    // Increase how many assets we have
    _rsvEngineReference.assetCount++;

   _rsvEngineReference.assetCollection[name] = new Audio();
   _rsvEngineReference.assetCollection[name].src = url
            _rsvEngineReference.assetCollection[name].addEventListener('canplaythrough',function(){
            _rsvEngineReference.numAssetsLoaded++;
        },false)

    _rsvEngineReference.assetCollection[name].load();
}

function playSound(name)
{
     _rsvEngineReference.assetCollection[name].play()
}
```

Comment: Including the code in your question would help tremendously.